# xml dom parsing

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I can't figure out how to access the data between the inner nested tags. When I run this javascript, all I see is "Null".

Here is what my xml file named "bboard.xml" looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Designed by Someone -->
<bulletinboard>
<article>
<title lang="en"><h2>eeeeeeeeegg #1</h2></title>
<detail><span class="detail">aaaaapple</span>&lt;a href="../data/csr.html#artcl1"> ...more &lt;/a></detail>
<date>12/09/09</date>
</article>
</bulletinboard>
```

Here is the javascript named "loadxmldoc.js":

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) 
{
try //Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  }
catch(e)
  {
  try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
    {
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
    }
  catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
  }
try 
  {
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load(dname);
  return(xmlDoc);
  }
catch(e) {alert(e.message)}
return(null);
}
```

And finally, here is the actual HTML page where I want to display the result of javascript.
It is called "javdemo.html":

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadxmldoc.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("bboard.xml");

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("detail");
var z=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("date");

document.write("<h4>"+"A Live Bulletin Board"+"</h4>");
       for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 

  document.write("<h1>"+x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</h1>"); 
  document.write(y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write(z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("<p>"+"&nbsp;"+"</p>");
  // document.write("</div>")
  }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This probably won't show the full code in your browser. By the way how do you escape html tags here on stack overflow?

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? Is it `<h1>eeeeeeeeegg #1</h1>aaaaapple12/09/09`?

Comment: Yes. The output should be eeeeeeeeeegg and aaaaaple when rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

...is OK. The `firstChild` of `z[0]` is a `Text` node, whose `nodeValue` (or `data`) is `'12/09/09'`.

```
x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

...isn't so good. `x[0]` is an `Element` node with `tagName` equal to `'h2'`. Elements don't have any `nodeValue`, hence the `null`.

You could say `x[i].firstChild.firstChild.data` to get the data from the `Text` node *inside* the `<h2>` element, assuming there's always exactly one.

Using `document.write` to output the strings you are getting is also problematic. If there's stuff like `&lt;script>` in the text content and you write that to HTML without escaping, you've got a cross-site-scripting vulnerability.

If what you actually need to do is extract the element content from the XML document, that's not so easy. There's no standard way to re-serialise node content from a plain XML Element like there is the HTML DOM with `HTMLElement.innerHTML`.

What you can do is recurse into the children re-creating the XML `Element` and `Text` nodes as HTML ones. The `document.importNode` method should be able to do this, except it doesn't work in IE, so you'd have to do it yourself:

```
<div id="board"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xdoc= loadXMLDoc('board.xml');
    var titles= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');
    var details= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('detail');
    var dates= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('date');

    var board= document.getElementById('board');
    for (var i= 0; i<titles.length; i++) {
        appendImportedInner(board, titles[i]);
        appendImportedInner(board, details[i]);
        board.appendChild(appendImportedInner(document.createElement('p'), dates[i]));
    }

    // Import Text and Element nodes inside a parent XML node to a target HTML node
    // Currently ignores any other type of node, such as comments
    //
    function appendImportedInner(dest, parent) {
        for (var i= 0; i<parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child= parent.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType==3) {  // TEXT_NODE
                dest.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child.data));
            }
            if (child.nodeType==1) {  // ELEMENT_NODE
                dest.appendChild(document.createElement(child.tagName));
                for (var ai= 0; ai<child.attributes.length; ai++) {
                    var attr= child.attributes[ai];
                    dest.lastChild.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value);
                }
                appendImportedInner(dest.lastChild, child);
            }
        }
        return dest;
    }
</script>
```

doing it with DOM methods allows you to forget nasty `document.write` and set the content at any time later in the load process, which also means you could make that XML document loading asynchronous with a callback to fill in the board, instead of the browser-pausing synchronous loader you've got at the moment.

In any case, `Document.load` as used in your current `loadXMLDoc()` is not a standard XML DOM method and won't work on WebKit (Chrome, Safari, ...). To load an XML file from the server you are better off using a normal `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch it: is simpler and much more widely compatible.

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting a completely blank page now in IE. Same thing in firefox too. Basically I wanted to show hyperlink link from xml and I can't think of any other way to do it, as you say serialise it from xml.

Comment: Works for me (just the above code block, after the `loadxmldoc` include).

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Just corrected "board.xml" to "bboard.xml".